# If a battery case falls apart is it safe to just glue it back together?

Tags: batteries, cases, glue

I've got a battery with two Li-Ion cells inside that has a two-parts rectangular case and those parts were somehow tightly connected (I guess glued together) but then fell apart and now the cells and the service electronics are in one half and the other half is just on its own. There's nothing like ventilation holes in that case.

If I just glue the case parts together carefully - will that pose any risk?

Comment: I think the case might be originally sealed by ultrasonic welding the plastic parts together: You can tell this by the lack of any glue remains between the parts.

Comment: @0x6d64: Quite likely - I didn't see any recognizable glue.

Comment: A photo would help (now why wasn't that obvious in the first place?).

Comment: @Olin Lathrop: I know and the only reason there's no photo and that's because the pack was glued back before the question was even planned to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No great risk compared to original condition **as long as**

- No part of the wiring is now more able to short circuit  to (connect with) some other part that is unintended.
- The batteries are as well supported and protected as before.

Lithium Ion  batteries are prone to "vent with flame" type sudden 'self-dismantlement' if subject to heavy discharge or if the battery casing is ruptured or penetrated by a sharp (or other) object.
 'Vent with flame' is not quite an explosion, but the difference is sometimes hard to spot - especially if you are standing close by, or you bag is in an aircraft overhead locker at the time, or inside your laptop :-(.

The following are examples of what **could** go wrong.
 All are very unlikely, but Murphy loves a challenge :-).

ie this is "no biggie", it should be easy to repair but **DO** do it properly as there is a small but finite change of "interesting outcomes" if you don't.

- If contact between two parts not intended to come in contact can occur the aboVe can apply.
- If you left a slit between the two halves that eg a steel ruler could slide into when both were in a bag together then the above could occur.
- If there was the opportunity for bits of foil (off candy or medicine etc) or a small coin to penetrate then the above can occur.
- If you dropped the battery and the case was able to re-separate under impact so that the batteries moved, then the above can occur.

Likley? - No.
 Interesting if it does? - Very.

---

You don't say what the battery pack is out of. If it's like a cellphone or laptop it may clip or slide into a present battery holding location and making it fatter with tape or ties may cause it not to fit. Worse, if you use thin tape or ies it may cause the battery to jam. Levering a LiIon battery out of something is better avoided if possible.

So - you say "glue together".
 How was it joined before? If their glue failed, why should yours last?

What is it made of? How long will your glue last?

If you can use a mechanical method that is easy and works well, consider using it.

Super glue (cyanacryloate) is good for positioning and quick tacking but has an unknown long term result with unknown plastics. Silicone rubber works for most plastics but has long pot life. Using the two together (on different locations on the case for each) gives you fast set and the long life of silicone rubber.

---

If the case was ultrasonically bonded originally, as has been suggested, it may be hard to glue (or not). Murphy says that if they did not need to glue the plastic there is a moderately good chance that they chose one that is hard to glue for whatever reason.

One option, usually not pretty but which can be effective, is to heat seal the two parts back together with a soldering iron or other suitable hot tool. You can also get specialised plastic welding tools which are (understandably) well suited to this task. Care needs to be taken not to overheat the batteries or to slip and insert a conductive iron tip into a suitably unfortunate location. Given due care this can be a good solution.

---

Play, Report. Enjoy

Comment: I used local franchise variation of Pattex Contact Adhesive (settles for 24 hours) - so far it holds okay. We'll see how the battery performs.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that gluing the case back together is a risk. The worst risk is in your case that the battery case comes off again and that the batteries are exposed to other damage like shorting the terminals or puncture by a pointed object.

If just gluing the halves back together will do the trick depends on the mechanical stress the case will encounter in the future: Maybe you want to wrap it in a layer of strong tape or use a pair of cable ties around the case for extra "safety". Make also sure, that your repair has to protect the battery from moisture.

Answer (score 1):

Could be at risk if the battery was not able to vent well, and came apart from pressure build up. I have seen this happen with Li-Ion where the case expanded and blew out the back of the device. A close inspection showed the cover was put on wrong, the vent holes were not facing the battery compartment.